# Clojure - dividing boolean

Tags: clojure

this code should output below, however, I am new to Clojure and don't understand how it works and would require some help.

```
(defn divide? [a b]
(zero? (mod a b)))

///output///
(divides? 2 10)
 => true
(divides? 4 10)
=> false
 /// output///
```

however actual output is:

```
 ///output///
 (divides? 2 10)
 => false
(divides? 4 10)
 => false
  /// output///
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Please describe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to switch your arguments to `mod` to get the correct output:

```
(defn divisible-by? [div num]
  (zero? (mod num div)))

(divisible-by? 4 10)  ;=> false
(divisible-by? 2 10)  ;=> true
(divisible-by? -2 10) ;=> true
```

For consistency with clojure.core's `mod`, `rem`, `quot`, etc., I'd consider swapping the arguments to your function so that the `num` comes first and `div` second.